# Finding method overload count in Java

Tags: java, overloading

In some projects I am currently working on, method overloading is being misused in many classes: methods with the same name are being overloaded for many times just with the difference of a parameter's presence or absence. And I want to change that.

Is there any existing tool that can count how many times a method is being overloaded in a Java class? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use reflection to get the `List<Method>`  [`getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) for a class and check for same name ([`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getName%28%29)) different signature methods ([`getParameterTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29))

Comment: Seems like a viable option, but still have to code something. I thought about writing a similar tool with BCEL. :-)